# Use Amazon CloudFront together with Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882595/are-there-any-difference-between-amazon-cloudfront-and-amazon-s3-transfer-accele) and understand the difference between CloudFront and S3 Transfer Acceleration. Since both can improve the download speed(though S3 Transfer Acceleration is mainly for uploading, it also improving download), can I use them together? Based on my test, it seems to be impossible as CloudFront will always take the S3 bucket URL like xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/ as the source. It cannot take xxx.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com as the source.

Comment: What is your actual _goal_? Are you experiencing slow transfer? What type of transfers are you doing? Where are your users located? Or is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, the purpose is to obtain better download speed if using them together. My visitors are world-wide. Not a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon CloudFront** caches content in [225+ Points of Presence](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/).

The first user who requests a piece of content in a particular location will trigger the edge location to 'pull' the content from the origin. Future requests for that content will be served from the cache. It is an excellent way to reduce latency for users spread around the world.

**Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration** *always* makes a request back to the source bucket. This is good for uploading, but does not reduce latency for users spread around the world since all of their requests would need to go to the source bucket.

You *might* be able to have **CloudFront in front of S3 Transfer Acceleration**, but CloudFront uses the AWS network to reach origin buckets, so it is unlikely to make any difference. If you do experiment with this, let us know your findings!

Comment: Thank you. I will make some tests on this.